# Name of book with comparison to Riddley walker on its cover

Tags: story-identification, languages

About a year ago I was at the local library browsing their SF and came across a book with a blurb on its cover (or possibly inside flap) comparing it, or at least some aspect of it, to *Riddley Walker*. I then ended up checking out *Riddley Walker*, but not the one that led me to it, and now I don't remember what it was. Does anyone know what it was?

I'm guessing the book is post-1980 since that was when *Riddley Walker* was published; I seem to recall it was within the past 10 years or so, but I might be wrong about this. I'm also trying to remember what aspect was actually being compared to; I think it may have been that they both used a constructed English dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps *[Book of Dave](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119114.The_Book_of_Dave)* by Will Self? It is relatively recent (2006) and many online reviews seem to make the comparison.

> When cabdriver Dave Rudman's wife of five years deserts him for another man, taking their only child with her, he is thrown into a tailspin of doubt and discontent. Fearing his son will never know his father, Dave pens a gripping text--part memoir, part deranged philosophical treatise, and part handbook of "the Knowledge" learned by all London cab drivers. Meant for the boy when he comes of age, the book captures the frustration and anxiety of modern life. Five hundred years later, the Book of Dave is discovered by the inhabitants on the island of Ham, where it becomes a sacred text of biblical proportion, and its author is revered as a mighty prophet.

Comment: I'm almost certain now this was it. It's on my to-read list now :)